# Get image coordinates in html and save the new appearance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a `structure` consisting of 2 png photos. one of them random `lines` and its `z-index` is 6 and the other is a bear photo and `z-index` is 5

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="kutu">
        <div class="cizgi">
          
        </div>
        <div class="resim1">

        </div>
      </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

```
.kutu {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url(background.jpg);

}

.resim1  {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-image: url(bear.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  
}

.cizgi {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(fe45bef1-0c56-46ea-a58e-998a46454321.png);
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

.The bear photo will always randomly occur anywhere in the box.The bear photo normally looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Dsj.png), but when the lines are on it, it's looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGviX.png).What I want is to create another div below and somehow reflect the new version of the bear photo i.e. the striped version. If this is exactly what I want, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukiLM.png) is it.

Comment: This article may assist you https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: Can you provide links to the images?

Comment: [Lines](https://gcdn.bionluk.com/uploads/order/fe45bef1-0c56-46ea-a58e-998a46454321.png)        [fully version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukiLM.png)